# Exchange 2013 reporting 5.1.1 for valid user

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, dsn

I've noticed that when we take down servers (including domain controller, or exchange), mail being delivered to VALID users by external servers get a 5.1.1 error as noted below.

```
2015-10-21.log:Oct 21 14:34:57 smtp1 sendmail[25335]: t9LFJ0tf010462: to=<test@domain.com>, delay=03:15:57, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp940, pri=455814, relay=x.x.x. [13.39.64.42], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

Is this normal behaviour for Exchange?  If not, is there a way to change exchange's behaviour so it doesn't report "user unknown" errors?  (Otherwise upstream servers get confused and cause problems)

(I tried to disguise some info in the above)

---

UPDATE: I tried shutting down the DC and could not generate a 5.1.1, and tried sending mail when the Exch server in startup/shutdown - but still couldn't generate a 5.1.1.  There must be some combination of the above which does this.  Hoping someone has ideas.

Comment: Is that the exchange server log for the smtp transaction?

Comment: The subject is locked, so I can't answer. But I think I have a possible cause for your specific error code. A 5.1.x can occur if a relay server does not find the user that you're attempting to relay a message to. So if your DC is down, and someone uses an smtp relay to send an e-mail to an internal contact, you will get a 5.1.x.

Comment: Just break the bestpractice and install the dc role on the server & install exchange on it.. no more syncro problem as it would be only 1 VM

Answer (score 4):

1. There's no good reason that I can think of that you would need to shut down any of your servers in order to back them up. There is a plethora of options and solutions for backing up live servers.
2. Exchange relies on Active Directory. It needs information from Active Directory. If Exchange can't communicate with a Domain Controller then Exchange isn't going to function properly.
3. Stop shutting down your servers to back them up and you won't have this problem.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - do you know if Exchange generates a 5.1.1 DSN when the DC is down?  Or when exchange is starting/stopping?

Comment: Do you KNOW that it generates a 5.1.1  when the DC is down?  (A 5.x.x is a permanent error which doesn't make sense if a DC is unavailable - I would expect a 4.x.x error)..or are you guessing?  I voted down your answer because it addresses everything EXCEPT what was asked (I did not ask about backup - you are making assumptions about my ability to backup a server)

Comment: Are users ever prompted for re-login? I've had an issue related to username, Outlook was expecting domain\username but I was providing username@domain.com and Exchange did not like that.

Comment: I'm hoping someone more informed can answer the actual question posted.  An unavailable DC should generate a 4.x transient error - since Exchange does not know if the mailbox exists or not.

Comment: @Telium This is perfectly reasonable and, as far as I can tell, correct. You are causing the problem yourself by shutting down servers unnecessarily.

Comment: The entire VM host has to go down - backup is a red herring.  The guests (including DC and Exch must go down as the SAN is going to go offline - again outside of relevance as to why).  The question is about the 5.x DSN and root cause.  An unavailable DC means account verification is unavailable - that's not the same as a user not in the domain.  That's the mystery I'm trying to shed light on.